# Problem with saving data of a profile in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I want to create a profile in my app, where I can edit or add some information when logged in. It already works with the checkbox but not with the other editText items. Also I want to show the saved information after I closed the app in the profile. Any idea how I could do this? Like changing an editText to a textView or is there any other way?

Here is my code of the fragment Profile:
(I tried several options to save data in the firebase database)

```
package com.example.discoverme

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import java.util.*
import java.util.Calendar.*


class ProfilFoto : Fragment() {

    lateinit var mDatabase : DatabaseReference
    var mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    var DISPLAY_NAME : String? = null


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_notifications)
        val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil_foto, container, false)


        Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(), "Profil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        Log.e("Halllo", "Hat toll geklapptttt")
        
        val telefon = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.telnummer) as EditText
        val geburtstag = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.geburtsdatum) as EditText
        val location = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.locationPerson) as EditText
        val stundenlohn = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.stundenlohn) as EditText

        var tele = telefon.text.toString()
        var gebi = geburtstag.text.toString()
        var loc = location.text.toString()
        var stundenl = stundenlohn.text.toString()

        val nameTxt: TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textName1)
        val emailTxt: TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailemail)
        val spezi = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.spezialisierungen)


        var uid = user!!.uid

        val userHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(uid)

        val speicherButton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.speichern)



        speicherButton.setOnClickListener {

            Log.e("Speichern", "speichert")


            Log.e("Telefon", tele)
                //userHashMap["Telefon"] = tele
                //mDatabase.child("Telefon").setValue(tele)

            mDatabase.child("Telefon").setValue(tele)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.e("Telefon", tele)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                    }


        if (!gebi.isEmpty()) {

            Log.e("Geburtstag", gebi)

            userHashMap["Geburtsdatum"] = gebi

           // mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
        }

        if (!loc.isEmpty()) {

            userHashMap["Adresse"] = loc

          //  mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
        }

        if (!stundenl.isEmpty()) {

            userHashMap["Stundenlohn"] = stundenl

           // mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
        }

            mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)



    }


        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                nameTxt.text = snapshot.child("Name").value.toString()
                emailTxt.text = snapshot.child("Email").value.toString()





                if (snapshot.child("Spezialisierung").exists()) {
                    Log.e("Spez", "Ist anscheinend da")
                    spezi.text = snapshot.child("Spezialisierung").value.toString()
                }

               /* if (snapshot.child("Telefon").exists()) {

                    telefon.text = snapshot.child("Telefon").value.toString()
                }
*/

            }
        })

        val buttonSignOut : ImageButton? = rootView.findViewById(R.id.signOut_button1)


        if (buttonSignOut != null) {
            buttonSignOut.setOnClickListener{
                mAuth.signOut()
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "Signed Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this.context, Start::class.java))

            }

        }

        val buttonspezi = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonspez)



        buttonspezi.setOnClickListener { view ->
            var dialog: AlertDialog

            // Initialize an array of colors
            val arrayColors = arrayOf("Hochzeit", "Portrait", "Familien", "Architektur", "Passfotos", "Lebensmittel", "Film", "Interior", " Kinder/Babies", "Landschaft", "Mode", "People und Lifestyle", "Werbung", "Sport", "Produkte", "Akt")

            // Initialize a boolean array of checked items
            val arrayChecked = booleanArrayOf(false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)


            var stringArray = arrayOf<String>()
            // Initialize a new instance of alert dialog builder object
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this.context)

            // Set a title for alert dialog
            builder.setTitle("Gib seine Spezialisierung an.")



            // Define multiple choice items for alert dialog
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(arrayColors, arrayChecked) { dialog, which, isChecked ->
                // Update the clicked item checked status
                arrayChecked[which] = isChecked

                // Get the clicked item
                val color = arrayColors[which]


            }


            // Set the positive/yes button click listener
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                // Do something when click positive button
                spezi.text = "Deine Spezialisierungen sind.. \n"
                for (i in 0 until arrayColors.size) {
                    val checked = arrayChecked[i]
                    if (checked) {

                        stringArray += arrayOf(arrayColors[i])
                        spezi.text = "${spezi.text}" + stringArray.toString()

                    }
                }
                userHashMap["Spezialisierung"] = stringArray.asList()

                Log.e("Liste", stringArray.asList().toString())

                mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
            }


            // Initialize the AlertDialog using builder object
            dialog = builder.create()

            // Finally, display the alert dialog
            dialog.show()
        }

        
            return rootView

    }

        // Method to show an alert dialog with multiple choice list items
    

    // Extension function to show toast message
    fun Context.toast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

and here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profil_foto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ProfilFoto">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="259dp"
            android:background="#9C27B0"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/signOut_button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="320dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="350dp"
                android:background="#9C27B0"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_logout_24"
                android:title="@string/sign_out"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                app:tint="#FFFFFF"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profil_wei_" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textName1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="700dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/infotext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Erzähle etwas über dich..."
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp">

                </EditText>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_on_24"
                    app:tint="#9C27B0" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/locationPerson"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Adresse"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_cake_24"
                    app:tint="#9C27B0" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/geburtsdatum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Geburtsdatum"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/telnummer"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_register_background"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_call_24"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Telefonnummer"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mail_full"
                    app:tint="#9C27B0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/emailemail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonspez"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Spezialisierungen"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttom_rounded_corner_lila"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/spezialisierungen"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:layout_margin="25dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_attach_money_24"
                    app:tint="#9C27B0" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/stundenlohn"
                    android:hint="Stundenlohn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />


            </LinearLayout>



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/speichern"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttom_rounded_corner_lila"
                    android:text="Änderungen speichern"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    app:cornerRadius="20dp">

                </Button>




        </LinearLayout>


        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="17dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just had to move the findViewById declaration inside the setOnClickListener and not only in the onCreate. Now I'm getting the ediText information and can save it in my firebase database.

Like so:

```
class ProfilFoto : Fragment() {

    lateinit var mDatabase : DatabaseReference
    var mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    var DISPLAY_NAME : String? = null


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_notifications)
        val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil_foto, container, false)


        Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(), "Profil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        Log.e("Halllo", "Hat toll geklapptttt")



        val nameTxt: TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textName1)
        val emailTxt: TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailemail)
        val spezi = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.spezialisierungen)


        var uid = user!!.uid

        val userHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(uid)

        val speicherButton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.speichern)



        speicherButton.setOnClickListener {

            val telefon = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.telnummer) as EditText
            val geburtstag = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.geburtsdatum) as EditText
            val location = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.locationPerson) as EditText
            val stundenlohn = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.stundenlohn) as EditText


            val tele = telefon.text.toString()
            val gebi = geburtstag.text.toString()
            val loc = location.text.toString()
            val stundenl = stundenlohn.text.toString()
            Log.e("Speichern", "speichert")

            if (!gebi.isEmpty()) {
                Log.e("Telefon", tele)
                //userHashMap["Telefon"] = tele
                //mDatabase.child("Telefon").setValue(tele)

                mDatabase.child("Telefon").setValue(tele)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon", tele)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                        }
            }


            if (!gebi.isEmpty()) {

                Log.e("Geburtstag", gebi)

                //userHashMap["Geburtsdatum"] = gebi

                mDatabase.child("Geburtstag").setValue(gebi)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon", gebi)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                        }

                // mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
            }

            if (!loc.isEmpty()) {

                Log.e("Location", loc)

                //userHashMap["Adresse"] = loc
                mDatabase.child("Adresse").setValue(loc)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon", loc)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                        }

                //  mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
            }

            if (!stundenl.isEmpty()) {

                // userHashMap["Stundenlohn"] = stundenl

                mDatabase.child("Stundenlohn").setValue(stundenl)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon", stundenl)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                        }
                // mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
            }

    }


        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                nameTxt.text = snapshot.child("Name").value.toString()
                emailTxt.text = snapshot.child("Email").value.toString()





                if (snapshot.child("Spezialisierung").exists()) {
                    Log.e("Spez", "Ist anscheinend da")
                    spezi.text = snapshot.child("Spezialisierung").value.toString()
                }

               /* if (snapshot.child("Telefon").exists()) {

                    telefon.text = snapshot.child("Telefon").value.toString()
                }
*/

            }
        })

        val buttonSignOut : ImageButton? = rootView.findViewById(R.id.signOut_button1)


        if (buttonSignOut != null) {
            buttonSignOut.setOnClickListener{
                mAuth.signOut()
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "Signed Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this.context, Start::class.java))

            }

        }
```

I just need to figure out how to show the saved information, in the profile after saving it once.